# ruby tIDENTIFIER error on logstash version 7.1.1

Tags: ruby, filter, syntax, null, logstash

we have ruby code in our logstash conf and we get syntax error while we pars it in logstash version 7.1.1
this it the code:

```
ruby {
init => "
def replace_null_string(h ,event , path)
h.each do |k,v|
if v == 'null'
event.set(path + '[' + k + ']', nil)
end
event.set(path + '[' + k + ']', nil)
if v.is_a?(Hash)
replace_null_string(h ,event , path + '[' + k + ']')
end
end
end
"
```

code => "
replace_null_string(event.to_hash,event, ' ')
"
}

and we get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateExeption: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SyntaxError) (ruby filter init) :1: syntax error, unexepected tIDENTIFIER

def replace_null_string(h ,event , path) h.each do |k,v| if v == 'null' event.set(path + '[' + k + ']', nil) end
event.set(path + '[' + k + ']', nil) if v.is_a?(Hash) replace_null_string(h ,event , path + '[' + k + ']') end end end
```

Comment: Ruby syntax doesn't necessarily let you take a valid format with multiple lines and have it all be on one line and still be valid. It looks like your logstash configuration took your Ruby function and made the entire thing one line or two lines, so you get a syntax error. Ruby does allow `;` as a statement separator, so you can put those in there which could be a quick fix for the issue as it will allow the function to be expressed in one line. I'm not familiar with using logstash, so I am not sure if there's another way to avoid the issue.

Comment: I think it's works !
thank you